# Error (2147024894) while opening .Net (C#) COM application into VB

Tags: c#, .net, com

I am developing plug in application for a third party software (They using COM technology to launch the plug in applications to their Software).I am using .Net(C#) for application development. The third party software was developed by VB. When i am trying to launch my plug in application to Third party software i am getting following error,
**DTM creation failed!(-2147024894 - File or assembly name TestComDTM, or one of its dependencies, was not found.)**
But i had copied all the required dependencies to installation location, but still I couldn't able to launch my application through third party software. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Decoding the HRESULT:

- -2147024894 is 0x80070002
- Which is much easier to look up in WinError.h (part of the Windows SDK).
- 7 is FACILITY_WIN32, so this is Windows, so looking at Win32 error codes for 2, which is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.
- So this is a file not found error as an HRESULT.

Which reflects the error message, but sometimes will tell you more about the route cause.

Next step: [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can be used to establish where COM is trying to load that file from.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check with [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) that all dependency are present, the profiling mode is really nice for that.

One thing that the standard windows message doesn't say is that it could appear if any dependency in the dependency graph of the application isn't found (Like if a dll you call  depends on another), and not only on direct dependencies not found.